# A dictionary with multiple entries with the same key

Tags: c#, collections

I need a Dictionary like object that can store multiple entries with the same key.  Is this avaliable as a standard collection, or do I need to roll my own?

To clarify, I want to be able to do something like this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, String>();
dict.Add(1, "first");
dict.Add(1, "second");

foreach(string x in dict[1])
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Output:

```
first
second
```

Comment: Are you looking to specifically use an int for the key? If a string would suffice, the NameValueCollection may be of use - multiple values can be assigned to a key

Answer (score 56, accepted):

In .NET 3.5 you can use a [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) instead of a Dictionary.

```
var items = new List<KeyValuePair<int, String>>();
items.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, String>(1, "first"));
items.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, String>(1, "second"));
var lookup = items.ToLookup(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value);

foreach (string x in lookup[1])
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

The `Lookup` class is immutable. If you want a mutable version you can use `EditableLookup` from [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/).

Comment: From the docs: *There is no public constructor to create a new instance of a Lookup<TKey, TElement>. Additionally, Lookup<TKey, TElement> objects are immutable, that is, you cannot add or remove elements or keys from a Lookup<TKey, TElement> object after it has been created.*

Comment: @Douglas: Thanks for the comment. I have updated my answer to cover this point.

Answer (score 16):

I would recommend doing something like this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, HashSet<string>>();
dict.Add(1, new HashSet<string>() { "first", "second" });
```

Comment: very smart, smart!!!

Answer (score 8):

`Dictionary<T,K>` does not support such behavior and there's no collection in the base class library providing such behavior. The easiest way is to construct a composite data structure like this:

```
var data = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
```

As the second parameter you should use a collection which provides the qualities you are looking for, i.e. stable order ⇒ `List<T>`, fast access `HashSet<T>`, etc.

Answer (score 7):

You definitely want to use NameValueCollection:

using System.Collections.Specialized;

```
NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
nvc.Add("pets", "Dog");
nvc.Add("pets", "Rabbit");
Console.WriteLine(nvc["pets"]);
//returns Dog,Rabbit
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for isn't actually a Dictionary in the traditional sense (see [Associative Array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array)).

There's no class, as far as I'm aware, that offers this in the framework (`System.Linq.Lookup` doesn't expose a constructor), but you could create a class yourself that implements `ILookup<TKey, TElement>`

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps use a Dictionary on your primary key, in which each element is a List or other collection on your secondary key.  To add an item to your data structure, see if the primary key exists.  If not, create a new single-item list with your Value and store it in the dictionary.  If the primary key does exist, add your Value to the list that's in the dictionary.