# One key and many different values in Dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

How can I store many different values in **`Dictionary`** under one key?

I have a code here:

```
Dictionary<string, DateTime> SearchDate = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();

SearchDate.Add("RestDate", Convert.ToDateTime("02/01/2013"));
SearchDate.Add("RestDate", Convert.ToDateTime("02/28/2013"));
```

but in Dictionary i learned that only one unique key is allowed, so my code is producing error.

Comment: You need a `Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>>`

Comment: This is called a ["Multimap"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimap) and cannot be implemented by the IDictionary contract (although you can do `Dictionary<string,IList<DateTime>>` or similar manually). If using LINQ, consider using [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx), although it has other implications.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/569903/multi-value-dictionary , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639972/a-dictionary-with-multiple-entries-with-the-same-key-c-sharp , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089850/c-sharp-dictionary-how-to-add-multiple-values-for-single-key , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101069/c-sharp-dictionary-one-key-many-values?rq=1 ,etc (-1 because I found these with `[c#] dictionary multiple` and `[c#] dictionary many` - you could have as well!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to make a `Dictionary` of some sort of container, for example

```
Dictionary<string,HashSet<DateTime>>
```

or

```
Dictionary<string,List<DateTime>>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>>`. Access the list by the key, and then add the new item to the list.

```
Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>> SearchDate = 
    new Dictionary<string, List<DateTime>>();
...
public void AddItem(string key, DateTime dateItem)
{
    var listForKey = SearchDate[key];
    if(listForKey == null)
    {
        listForKey = new List<DateTime>();
    }
    listForKey.Add(dateItem);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You may try using a [Lookup Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx). To create it you may use [Tuple Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268536.aspx):

```
var l = new List<Tuple<string,DateTime>>();
l.Add(new Tuple<string,DateTime>("RestDate", Convert.ToDateTime("02/01/2013")));
l.Add(new Tuple<string,DateTime>("RestDate", Convert.ToDateTime("02/28/2013")));

var lookup = l.ToLookup(i=>i.Item1);
```

However, if you need to modify the lookup, you'll have to modify the original list of tuples and update the lookup from it. So, it depends on how often this collection tends to change.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx) class if you are using .NET 3.5

Comment: One thing to be aware of is Lookup is not mutable. You can not add more elements once it has been created.